# Python lambda - is it necessary in such case?

Tags: python, lambda

`lambda xxx: foo(xxx)` - is it the totally same as just `foo`?
used in construction like
`map(lambda xxx: foo(xxx), my_things)`

I dont see any difference:

```
def plus(a):
    return a+1
for i in map(plus, [1,2,3]):
    print(i)
for i in map(lambda a: plus(a), [1,2,3]):
    print(i)
```

prints the same

```
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's right. `lambda x: foo(x)` is the same as just calling `foo(x)`.

Remember that a `lambda` is just an **anonymous function** that does something to `x`. In this case, it just calls `foo` on `x` and returns the result of `foo(x)`.

For example, calling `(lambda x: foo(x), 60)` is similar to doing this:

```
def function2(y):
    return y*2

def function1(x):
    return function2(x)

function1(60)
```

Answer (score 5):

No, `lambda x: foo(x)` is not the same as `foo(x)` but rather `foo`. The eta reduction is the conversion of `lambda x: foo(x)` to `foo`.

`map(lambda a: plus(a), [1,2,3])` and `map(plus, [1,2,3])` are related by replacing `lambda a: plus(a)` with `plus` an application of the eta reduction rule.

Comment: yeah, that's right about `foo` not `foo(x)`, that's excatcly what I meant, I'll edit my question, thank you